# Limpiar un recordset C#

Tags: c#, lista, delete, recordset

Bien, tengo un clase llamada STOCK en donde tengo una variable publica llamada "listaSAP" esta variable es de tipo Recordset.

```
 public Recordset recordset_lista_sap;
```

El detalle es el siguiente, tengo dos funciones A y B, que ejecutan una consulta SQL y cargan este Recordset, el problema es que necesito que cuando se ejecute B tengo que limpiar ese Recordset.

Encontre la forma de hacerlo usando el metodo delete, pero este metodo solo funciona para eliminar un registro del Recordset, por lo que tengo que aplicar un While para eliminar todos.

```
 private static void LimpiarRecordSet(DataTable listaSAP)
    {
        int totalRows = listaSAP.Rows.Count;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < totalRows)
        {
            listaSAP.Rows[i].Delete();
            totalRows = listaSAP.Rows.Count;
            i++;
        }
    }]
```

Tambien lo puedo hacer con un EoF, el punto es que esto consume tiempo porque son mas de 80mil registros. Hay alguna forma de simplemente eliminarlos como con una lista? ya saben usando un Clear

```
ListaSAP.Clear();
```

Comment: listaSAP.Reset(); ?????

Comment: @Yussef se carga las columnas, los datos todo para borrar solo los datos, eso es mejor usar listaSAP.Clear();

Comment: @rexxarcat Supongo que será mejor, pero el OP lo pone al final, así que supuse que por algún motivo esotérico necesitaba otra solución. En todo caso, ahora que leo bien la pregunta, el OP se refiere a un tipo de dato `Recordset` y este tipo por lo menos a mí no me aparece, supongo que estará usando una librería de 3ros

Comment: Si aunque no se seguro cual podria ser solo conozco el de ADODB

Comment: Aun asi si el datatable no es de la libreria el clear tendria que funcionar si es ADODB lo que usa

Comment: La libreria que estoy usando es **using SAPbobsCOM;** para generar los recordset